# Basic text formatting during text input with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I know that is possible to programmatically format a text in Codename One using something like "Rich Text View". But in my use case the user can do basic formatting of the text.

For example, see the following two screenshots of the Protonmail app. How can I do something similar with Codename One?

In the first screenshot, "Taglia" means "Cut" and "Copia" means "Copy".
In the second screenshot, "Grassetto" means "Bold" and "Corsivo" means "Italic".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support that. This behavior is very inconsistent between platforms and pretty limited in all native platforms so implementing it in a cross platform way isn't practical.

However, since all platforms have good HTML5 support it's pretty easy to implement it with a `WebView` by embedding a web based rich edit widget. Since these consistently work with HTML the results are cross platform and should be easy to work with. In the past we had a CKEditor cn1lib but I think it's out of date by now. The core concept should work though and should be much easier to implement as we now support the html package for deploying web resources. So you can take any HTML based text editor and just place the files under the `src/html` directory then open that hierarchy for editing.